# Strange behaviour with jquery hover function

Tags: jquery, hover, stylesheet

I have the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                 $(".firstlevel").hover(
                    function()
                    {
                        $(this).find("li")
                            .css({"display": "block", 
                            "margin-left": "120px", 
                            "list-style-type": "circle"});
                    },

                    function()
                    {
                        $(this).find("li")
                            .css({"display": "none", 
                            "margin-left": "120px", 
                            "list-style-type": "circle"});
                    });
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            .firstlevel
            {
                list-style-type:disc;
                margin-left:40px;
            }

            .firstlevel li
            {
                list-style-type:square;
                margin-left:80px;
            }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>

    <ul>
        <li class="firstlevel"><a href="#">One</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One-One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One-Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="firstlevel"><a href="#">Two</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Two-One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two-Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>       

    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is that I should hover over the 'One' and 'Two' links and see the sublinks appear and disappear, using the jquery `hover` function. I also want to see that the list style of the sublinks changes to a circle, and the sublinks become more indented.

What is odd is that when I do the mouseover, the indentation of the sublinks **does** change as expected, but the bullets to the sublinks disappear altogether. This happens in Chrome, but not in IE.

On inspection, it looks like Chrome's user agent stylesheet is overwriting my set styles.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I would try controlling the display with a class instead: http://jsfiddle.net/keegan3d/WZJt2/

Comment: That's a good idea. However, your example doesn't exactly do what I want - I want to be able to change the styling of the sublinks to be different from their initial styling when I mouseover. I tried creating a `show` class with `display:block` and `list-style-type:circle`, then using `addClass("show").removeClass("hide")` on hover mouseover, and `addClass("hide").removeClass("show")` on mouseout, but that didn't make any difference. :(

Comment: Ok I think this is doing what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/keegan3d/WZJt2/2/. I had to change the css selectors to li.show and li.hide to increase their score: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgvPrzjDfmw#t=14m

Comment: Hi Keegan, thanks for your help. Your code works perfectly in jsfiddle, but like I said, if you take it and save it to your local machine, **then** open it in Chrome, you'll see that although the new indent style for the sublinks is used, the bullet style is thrown away. I'm thinking that this must be a Chrome bug, so I don't think I'll pursue the issue, but you can see if you can repro this if you like (using Chrome only).